# how can i get the value of object in a method in service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a method called "login" in the authentificationService and i do copy of the return result into object called "securityObject"

```
 securityObject: AppUserAuth = new AppUserAuth();

 login(entity: AppUser): Observable<AppUserAuth> {
    // Initialize security object
    this.resetSecurityObject();

    return this.http.post<AppUserAuth>(API_URL + "login",
      entity, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap(resp => {
          // Use object assign to update the current object
          // NOTE: Don't create a new AppUserAuth object
          //       because that destroys all references to object
          Object.assign(this.securityObject, resp);
          // Store into local storage
          localStorage.setItem("bearerToken",
            this.securityObject.bearerToken);
        }));
  }
```

this the class of the appUserAuth :

```
export class AppUserAuth {
  id: number = null;
  name: string = "";
  token: string = "";
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
  firstName: string= "";
  lastName: string= "";
  numberProduct: null;
```

my probleme is i tried to call the value of the object securityObject from the service AuthentificationService and i get nothing

productService:

```
securityObject: AppUserAuth = null;
constructor(private authentificationService: AuthentificationService) {
    this.securityObject = authentificationService.securityObject;
  }

ngOnInit() {
    console.log("securityobject value =",this.securityObject)
  }
```

Comment: I suggest using [an rxjs `BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) and subscribe to it in consumers of the authentication service. The problem you're having is that if you try to use `authentificationService.securityObject` before `login()` has been called, it is an empty `AppUserAuth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the simple variable with `BehaviorSubject` (RxJS) and expose it as `Observable` to prevent consumers from next-ing it. As follows (not tested):

**Auth Service:**

```
private securityObjectSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<AppUserAuth>(new AppUserAuth());
securityObject$ = this.securityObjectSubject$.asObservable();
    
login(entity: AppUser): Observable<AppUserAuth> {
    // Initialize security object
    this.resetSecurityObject();
    
    return this.http.post<AppUserAuth>(API_URL + "login", entity, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap(resp => {
          // Use object assign to update the current object
          this.securityObjectSubject$.next(resp); // <= this is the assignment
          // Store into local storage
          localStorage.setItem("bearerToken",
              this.securityObjectSubject$.value.bearerToken);
        }));
  }
```

**Product Service:**

```
securityObject: AppUserAuth = null;
constructor(private authentificationService: AuthentificationService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    authentificationService.securityObject$.subscribe(value => {
        this.securityObject = value;
        console.log("securityobject value =", this.securityObject)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`securityObject` only will have the value once you subscribe to `login` method.

The reason you get nothing is because getting `securityObject` is async operation so it can't be resolved at constructor moment.

So try to subscribe to `login` method in `ngOnInit` and then change detection will do the job.